# Drop R data.frame columns based on Row Value

Tags: r, dataframe, shiny

I have a dataFrame setup like this:

```
dfRiskChanges <<- data.frame(-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1)
colnames(dfRiskChanges) <<- c('Funcational', 'Steroid', 'HxCHF', 'SOB',
                            'HxCOPD', 'Smoker', 'DMAll', 'HTNMed')
```

Then I replace the applicable dataFrame values with real numbers, so a final version of the dataFrame could be:

```
Funcational Steroid HxCHF SOB HxCOPD   Smoker    DMAll        HTNMed
-1          -1      -1     -1   -1        -1        1.983131    -1 0.6438011
```

Now I want to drop all the columns where the value is -1.

I've been trying things like this:

```
dfRiskChanges.new <- dfRiskChanges[dfRiskChanges$units != -1, ]
```

and

```
dfRiskChanges.new <<- dfRiskChanges %>% filter(units != -1)
```

and

```
dfRiskChanges %>% select_if(function(col) all(col != -1))
```

All without success. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Why are you using `<<-` so much?

Comment: will the length of the column be always 1?

Comment: `dfRiskChanges <- t(dfRiskChanges); t(dfRiskChanges[dfRiskChanges[,1] != -1, ])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's add another column with a different value:

```
>dfRiskChanges$NoSmoke=0
> dfRiskChanges
  Funcational Steroid HxCHF SOB HxCOPD Smoker DMAll HTNMed NoSmoke
1          -1      -1    -1  -1     -1     -1    -1     -1       0
```

Next, return only the columns that don't have -1 in them:

```
> df2=dfRiskChanges[!grepl(-1,dfRiskChanges)] #picks out all columns that don't contain -1
> df2
  NoSmoke
1       0
```

Comment: I changed the 0 in your example to a -1 and it works perfectly! Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `select_if` function from `dplyr`, I modified your code a little bit as follows.

```
dfRiskChanges <- data.frame(
  'Funcational' = -1,
  'Steroid' = -1,
  'HxCHF' = -1,
  'SOB' = -1,
  'HxCOPD' = -1, 
  'Smoker' = 1.983131,
  'DMAll' = -1,
  'HTNMed' = 0.6438011
  )

library(dplyr)
dfRiskChanges %>% select_if(function(col) sum(col) != -1)
```